# grep and multiply certain columns

Tags: shell-script, shell

In a file, I have a certain construct:

```
------------------------------
|  1   123.456    789.1011 T |
|  2   789.123    234.1234 T |
------------------------------
 All true
```

I can

```
grep -s -B 3 "All true" file.out | head -n 2
```

to get only the relevant lines

```
|  1   123.456    789.1011 T |
|  2   789.123    234.1234 T |
```

How would I now go on to get the first numbers (`123.456` and `789.123`) in variables, but multiplied by a certain value `x`

Is there a way to get the `n`'th argument of a grepped line or something?

Comment: You are looking for `cut`. See `man cut` and option `-f`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short ***grep*** + ***awk*** approach:

Let's say, the multiplier is `3`:

```
grep -sB 3 "All true" file.out | awk -v x=3 '$1=="|"{ print $3*x }'
```

The output:

```
370.368
2367.37
```

---

- `-v x=3` - passing multiplier as `x` variable into *awk* script

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Philippos, I managed to get the answer:

```
number=$(grep -s -B 3 "All true" file.out | head -n 2 | cut -d' ' -f6 )

for i in ${number}
do
  echo "$i*$x" | bc -l
done
```